# MATLAB: assignin caller to variables performance issues

Tags: performance, matlab

I have variables outside a particular function, which I want to put in a workspace. I do this by using `assignin('caller'...`.
As a test case, I did the same scenario, one as described above, and the other as simply defining a duplicate scenario within the main function (code below)

Quite simply there is a performance issue with this, here are my results:

> **normal**
>   Elapsed time is 1.613414 seconds.
>   **assignin('caller',...**
>   Elapsed time is 1.849663 seconds.

The timing is not significant here, but it does matter as number of (single) variables increase. I see orders of magnitude performance decrease in my work. I checked that both versions give the exact same results at the end

*note: For some strange reason in my code not present here, I have many matrices and single-variables each involved in operations and computations. If matrices are called with `assignin('caller'...`, there is literally **no performance hit**. With single variables, the problem in performance arises.*

**MATLAB versions tested in:**

- 2013a Win7-64bit (*me*)
- 2010b Win7-64bit (*Luis Mendo*)

### **CODE**

```
function sof

sig = 0.3;
max_iter = 100000;
% in functiond efined variables
y1 = 2.5;
y2 = 7.3;
y3 = 3.4;
y4 = 7.2;
y5 = 2.2;
y6 = 1.7;
y7 = 9.2;
k = zeros(1,max_iter);

% defined elswhere using assignin 'caller'
get_vars (max_iter);

% perform calculations with variables defined here
tic
for i=1:max_iter
    k(i) = normrnd(y1,sig)/y2*y3*y4/y5*y6/y7/y1*y2 + y1*y3*y5/y2;
end
toc

% perform calculations with variables defined with assignin('caller',...;
tic
for i=1:max_iter
    k_a(i) = normrnd(x1,sig)/x2*x3*x4/x5*x6/x7/x1*x2 + x1*x3*x5/x2;
end
toc

end

function get_vars (mrange)
    assignin('caller','x1',2.5);
    assignin('caller','x2',7.3);
    assignin('caller','x3',3.4);
    assignin('caller','x4',7.2);
    assignin('caller','x5',2.2);
    assignin('caller','x6',1.7);    
    assignin('caller','x7',9.2);   
    assignin('caller','k_a',zeros(1,mrange ));
end
```

Comment: Also slower here. Matlab 2010b, Win7 64 bits

Comment: Funny thing: if the variable name `i` is changed to `ii` (to avoid overriding the imaginary unit) the performance gap seems to increase

Comment: @LuisMendo I tried that too, same slow performance. This is all pretty strange to be honest - especially when there is no problems with matrices as far as I've tested!